# Dockerize and deploy the Spring App that has Kafka consumer on AKS?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka, azure-aks

At present, we have a Java spring boot application deployed on the VM which consumers the message from Kafka.

We have an Enterprise Kafka Cluster deployed on the VMs. It uses the standard ports - eg: 9092 & 2181.

**Requirement**:
We want to deploy this application Azure Kubernetes Services (AKS).

**Ask** : Is there anything specific (eg: port ) needs to be done in the dockerfile or kubernetes manifest yaml?

I would assume that as long as the AKS can connect (VNET - VNET) with the Kafka Cluster that should be sufficient.

please suggest.

Comment: What have you tried? Specifically, a containerized client will run the same as if it were on a host (or VM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka clients don't need to expose any port mappings

Your assumption is correct, that given the proper VPC settings, then communicate should be fine.